# C#: Wrapper for Entity Framework seeks abstract static method implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

My wrapper for implementing an Entity Framework entity as a Model for an MVC application has hit a snag. The wrapper is defined as an abstract generic class, like so:

```
public abstract class EntityModel<E> : IValidatableObject
{
    public Int64 ID { get; protected set; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext 
        validationContext);
    public abstract IEnumerable<ValidationResult> EntityAdd();
    public abstract IEnumerable<ValidationResult> EntityUpdate();
    public abstract IEnumerable<ValidationResult> EntityDelete();

    /* public static abstract IEnumerable<EntityModel<E>> EntityGetList(
        Expression<Func<E, bool>> matchPredicate); */
}
```

Obviously, the commented out section has the fundamental flaw of being a static AND an abstract method, which C# does not allow, even in a generic class. The method EntityGetList is meant to be called without an instance of EntityModel<E>, to acquire an IEnumerable<EntityModel<E>> that meets the matchPredicate condition, like so:

```
public class MyEntityModel : EntityModel<MyEntity>
{
    public static IEnumerable<MyEntityModel> 
        EntityGetList(Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> matchPredicate)
    {
        /* implementation details here, usually involving a LINQtoEntities call 
            with .Where(matchPredicate).ToList() and a foreach() that converts 
            the list of MyEntity to a list of MyEntityModel */
    }
}

// elsewhere ...

IEnumerable<MyEntityModel> partialViewModel = MyEntityModel.EntityGetList(e => 
    e.MyEntityProperty == value);
```

Since EntityGetList is one of the methods used to acquire instances of EntityModel-derived classes to act upon, it doesn't make sense to require an instance of MyEntityModel in order to get a list of unrelated instances of it.

The question is, is there a way to add EntityGetList to the template, to require that derived classes implement it? Changing EntityModel<E> to an interface is out, as there are already non-abstract methods included that I haven't listed for brevity's sake, like EntitySave(), which attempts to call EntityUpdate(), and if that fails, EntityAdd(), and if both fail, returns a list of ValidationResults produced by both attempts. I keep thinking that there should be a way to declare a generic static method that acts like an abstract method, but I keep drawing a blank and/or compiler error.

Comment: You starting point is wrong. Not only the static method, but *none* of these methods belong in an entity class. It defeats the repository/unit-of-work architecture of Entity Framework.

Comment: Agreed, you should be creating repositories that get/add/update/delete your entities.

Comment: Hmm. This was the recommended practice when the project was started about a year ago, for creating a model that interacts with the Entity Framework. Guess I'd better look up details on this repository/unit of work stuff. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Well, having read up on the Repository/Unit-of-Work architecture, it turns out this was exactly what I am implementing with my generic template. Maybe the fact that my CRUD methods on the EntityModel<E> class return IEnumerable<ValidationResult> instead of void is confusing you?